# How to replace whitespace with and operator in solr query

Tags: solr, whitespace, lucene, query-analyzer

I have implemented solr search o my site. When I search the query "Red Shoes", it is showing results for both Red and shoes. But I wants solr to show those records which contains both keywords "Red" and "Shoes". It it related to whitespace tokenizer ??. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default operator.  By default, it is `OR`, just like in the core Lucene standard query parser.  You can set it to `AND` in [your schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator) with:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

Or in your [query string with `q.op`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#q.op), like:

```
{!lucene q.op=AND df=text}red shoes
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, but to be more specific, [LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) are the way to go here. The version in schema.xml is being considered for deprecation (see [SchemaXml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator) for more information).